# Postgresql Average and Group By

Tags: database, postgresql, timestamp

So I have a table with a column id(INTEGER), temperature(REAL) and one time(TIMESTAMP) and I want to make the average temperature by hour but I can't work it around.

For a sample with

```
 temperature |        time      
-------------+---------------------
       21.88 | 2018-06-01 07:30:00
       23.21 | 2018-06-01 07:45:00
       23.57 | 2018-06-01 08:15:00
       24.91 | 2018-06-01 08:30:00
        25.5 | 2018-06-01 08:45:00
       25.98 | 2018-06-01 09:00:00
             | 2018-06-01 09:30:00
       24.45 | 2018-06-01 09:45:00
             | 2018-06-01 10:00:00
```

And the request:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(DATE_PART('hour',time)) time, avg(temperature) 
FROM Measure GROUP BY time , DATE_PART('hour',time);
```

I get:

```
        time         |       avg        
---------------------+------------------
 2018-06-01 07:30:00 | 21.8799991607666
 2018-06-01 08:15:00 | 23.5699996948242
 2018-06-01 09:00:00 | 25.9799995422363
```

Something is happening here, but it's not an average...

### Resolved:

Thanks to the comment, I get something correct with the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(DATE_TRUNC('hour',time)) DATE_TRUNC('hour',time), avg(temperature) 
FROM Measure GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('hour',time), DATE_TRUNC('day',time);
```

Comment: Use date_trunc () to give date and hour then group by that. You need both the daye and hour of day.

Comment: Yup, good call, thank you!